# How to listen multiple button clicks in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a products.html site where all the product are listed in a container and where you can add them to cart by using "Add to cart" button. My sites body looks like this

```
<body>
  <header>
    <nav class="navbar">
      <ul class="nav-links">
        <li><a href="index.html">Front Page</a></li>
        <li><a href="register.html">Register</a></li>
        <li><a href="users.html">List Users</a></li>
        <li><a href="products.html">List Products</a></li>
        <li><a href="cart.html">Shopping Cart</a></li>
     </ul>
   </nav>
</header>
<main>
  <h1>Products</h1>
  <div id="notifications-container"></div>
  <div id="products-container"></div>
</main>
<footer>
  <p>Copyright &copy; 2020 diipadaa etc etc.</p>
</footer>
<template id="product-template">
  <div class="item-row">
    <h3 class="product-name"></h3>
    <p class="product-description"></p>
    <p class="product-price"></p>
    <button>Add to cart</button>
  </div>
</template>
<script src="js/utils.js"></script>
<script src="js/products.js"></script>
```

I have multiple product which i read and place them into the site by using the clone method.

```
const baseContainer = document.querySelector('#products-container');
const productTemplate = document.querySelector('#product-template');

products.forEach(product => {
const { name, description, price, _id } = product;
const productContainer = productTemplate.content.cloneNode(true);

productContainer.querySelector('.product-name').id = `name-${_id}`;
productContainer.querySelector('.product-name').textContent = name;

productContainer.querySelector('.product-description').id = `description-${_id}`
productContainer.querySelector('.product-description').textContent = description;

productContainer.querySelector('.product-price').id = `price-${_id}`;
productContainer.querySelector('.product-price').textContent = price;

document.getElementsByTagName('button').forEach(elem => {
  console.log(elem);
});


baseContainer.append(productContainer);
});
```

If i have for example 15 products on the site how can i listen to every "Add to cart" button click and call a function to it. the buttons have no id or class. forEach doesnt work for me so it doesnt regonize that there is multiple buttons?

Comment: Delegate the event: https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate

Comment: [What is DOM Event delegation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1687296)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you clone the button, you should give it an attribute to define what product it is associated with. Something like

```
products.forEach(product => {
  const { name, description, price, _id } = product;
  const productContainer = productTemplate.content.cloneNode(true);
  //add a reference to the product ID in the button
  productContainer.setAttribute("data-productID", _id);
  ...
```

Answer (score -1):

Change

```
document.getElementsByTagName('button')
```

to

```
productContainer.getElementsByTagName('button')
```

Before you append, it does not exist in the document.

Comment: I get this error "TypeError: productContainer.getElementsByTagName is not a function" if i use it. Why doesnt that work?

Comment: Hmm. if you clone an element, it will return an element.  So the product container should be an element, right?  perhaps you should change `productTemplate.content.cloneNode(true)` to be `productTemplate.firstElementChild.cloneNode(true)` instead.  @TeemuHarju